# Can the lifts (elevators) be called?

Tags: battlefield-4

On some maps where there are lifts (e.g. Hainan Resort), is it possible to call the lift down to your floor?

I'm wondering if the lift automatically returns to the original floor after it has used by a player (i.e. a player getting in then activating the button), or you can call the lift to different floors (e.g. on Hainan Resort there are lifts on the first level but you can't seem to enter on them, unless I've missed something, hence my question).

Comment: Would you mind changing the accepted answer?

Comment: OK, I've accepted the correct answer now I've had chance to experiment myself. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They cannot be "called" because they don't have a position! **The elevators are open at both ends simultaneously.**

When a button is pressed, the doors close on both ends at the same time, and it **swap-teleports** players (if any) within the top-room with players (if any) in the bottom-room, opening the doors (for both rooms) when it is done. Neither room moves, it simply uses some visual tricks to imply movement.

This means that two players can both be riding an elevator up/down and never see one-another because they keep switching spots.

Comment: This is the correct answer as both doors are open at the same time. The poster also notes correctly the lifts do not move, instead they teleport the player (which can result in odd bugs on Siege of Shanghai if the buttons appear in the rubble once the building has collapsed).

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding and experience, mainly with the Siege of Shanghai and Hainan Resort maps, is that the lifts function on a weird state system. When in the "open" state, the lift doors are open and you can enter and activate the lift. When activated, the lift switches to the "closed" state. The doors are closed on both floors and the contents of the lift are being transported. After a certain wait time, the contents are transported (soldiers that started on the lower floor will be transported to the upper floor and vice-versa), the doors open, and the lift switches to its "open" state.

This has some interesting implications as you could stand inside the lift and wait for someone else to attempt to travel to your floor and you would essentially switch places. I'll try to do some testing on this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've only played BF4 on console on the 360 and as far as I seen, the lifts (if you're talking about the elevators) are teleports (at least on the 360). If you look at an objective, you can obviously wait in a elevator while looking at the objective hud icon and you'll see it just pop below you a couple thousand feet (assuming you went up). Though if some one is currently still using the elevator, you do have to wait until they reach their floor.

If I'm also correct, not all lifts are accessible in the Hainan Resort building. Only there for looks.

Comment: For Hainan Resort both lifts are active, but one of them connects the ground-floor and the roof, while the other one connects the first-floor to the roof.